# How to make coupon codes mandatory on checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I need to have the check out process done by the vendor himself not by the customer and that is how :

I need to make the coupon code mandatory ( to be added by the vendor) so the 
 "proceed to check out " button is not active unless the coupon code is added, and after the vendor adds the code, the order is completed.

Comment: Welcome to the site @QueenEve. If you want to improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, I suggest you add more information like what you've tried yet, and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend the use of javascript to prevent the user from clicking the checkout button.

Each button has a "disabled" state, at which the button is greyed out (by default) and cannot be clicked on (similar to the update cart button when no changes have been made). Simply add the disabled state to the checkout button onLoad, then remove that state when a coupon has been applied (button click event on the apply coupon button).

Comment: Thank you Nixivious for your quick response, can you help me with this code? and if not how can I have this done please?
sorry for asking these detailed questions but I really dont know how to do it 

and thanks again for your support.